# How to import a configurable product multiple attributes?

Tags: configurable-product, import, magento-enterprise-2

I have been using `Magento EE 2.1.7` and trying to import a configurable product with 2 attributes: `shoe size` and `shoe width`.

I manually **created 1 configurable with several simple** and exported those for a template to create more.

When importing from a `csv` it's only adding one of the configurable options.

I have tried several `variations` in the column `configurable_variations`.

If I **try to add both attributes** I get an `error on import`. If I leave this like export it only adds one option.

So how to import a configurable product with 2 or more attributes.

Thanks

Comment: which variation you have tried let me know.

Comment: I did get this to work, I also found someone created a simple module to export properly. I will update later with full details.

Answer (score 1):

I did get this to work. I also found a module someone else made that exports the configurable_variations. I also found that when exporting full catalog it was leaving that column out all together, but exporting in smaller batches it would work better. tonight I will also add a sample csv here and link to module.